# Have a Button with 3 different background images. Android Studio, XML, Java

Tags: java, android, xml

can somedy help me, and tell me whats wrong in this code?
I have 3 different background pictures of my shack, (green, grey, normal)
and in the Java Code below i check which state is active

[image: the code]

Comment: please don't post images of code, include your code in your question

Comment: You haven't specified what is the issue. Is you image not showing at all? Or is it misbehaving only for some states?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly set the image of button in different conditions like this:-

```
((ImageButton)shackButton).setImageResource(R.drawable.<imageid>);
```

You can do it without creating any other resource file.

Answer (score 0):

change your xml to this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shack1000green" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shack1000grey" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/shack1000" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    </selector>
```